# Logic, truth tables p ∧ q p and q are false, why is the entire statement false and not true?

Tags: logic

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why if P is false and Q is false, then why the statement,

"P ∧ Q" is false. If Both things are the same (both are false), and I am saying "P and Q" why is this statement false and not true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will date her if she is beautiful and smart. If she is ugly and dumb I will NOT date her, those won't cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

"P and Q" is true iff P is true and Q is true.

Answer (score 0):

Either  $p $ or $q $ being false make   $p \land q $ false.   So certainly  both being false does...